# Error with two almost identical pieces of code

Tags: c, debugging, typedef, comparator

**I am new to C so please keep that in mind when answering

I'm currently working on a larger program where I use classes called integer.c (which defines an integer and functions used on it), real.c (which defines a double and functions used on it) and comparator.c (which defines functions used to compare these different data types (each class does have a header as well).

When I try and compile the larger program, I get an error in my comparator.c file stating:

```
    comparator.c:25:23: error: expected expression
        return ((integer *) p)->value - ((integer *) q->value);
                          ^
    comparator.c:25:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'integer'
        return ((integer *) p)->value - ((integer *) q->value);
                 ^
    comparator.c:25:48: error: expected expression
        return ((integer *) p)->value - ((integer *) q->value);
                                                   ^
    comparator.c:25:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'integer'
        return ((integer *) p)->value - ((integer *) q->value);
                                          ^
    comparator.c:23:25: warning: unused parameter 'p' [-Wunused-parameter]
    int intComparator(void *p, void *q)
                            ^
    comparator.c:23:34: warning: unused parameter 'q' [-Wunused-parameter]
    int intComparator(void *p, void *q)
                                     ^
```

Here is my comparator.c class and I want to note how my intComparator functions and realComparator functions are almost identical so I cannot see why I do not get these errors for my realComparator:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <assert.h> 
    #include <string.h> 
    #include "comparator.h"
    #include "str.h"
    #include "integer.h"
    #include "real.h"

    //returns >0 if p is > q, returns 0 if equal, returns <0 is q is > p
    int intComparator(void *p, void *q)
    {
        return ((integer *) p)->value - ((integer *) q)->value;
    }

    ////returns >0 if p is > q, returns 0 if equal, returns <0 is q is > p
    double realComparator(void *p,void *q)
    {
        return ((real *) p)->value - ((real *) q)->value;
    }


    int stringComparator(void *p,void *q)
    {
        int r = strcmp((char *)p, (char *)q);
        return r;
    }
```

Here is my integer.c class and real.c class for comparison (please note that any programming style of this program that might seem weird is because it is for a class project where I need to follow style and program outline instructions):

integer.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include "integer.h"

    extern void Fatal(char *,...);

    integer *
    newInteger(int x)
        {
        integer *p = malloc(sizeof(integer));
        if (p == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"out of memory\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        p->value = x;
        return p;
        }

    int 
    getInteger(integer *v)
        {
        assert(v!=0);
        return v->value;
        }

    void 
    displayInteger(FILE *fp,void *v)
        {
        assert(v!=0);
        fprintf(fp,"%d",getInteger((integer *) v));
        }

    void
    freeInteger(integer *v)
        {
        free(v);
        }
```

real.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    extern void Fatal(char *,...);

    real *
    newReal(double x)
    {
        real *p = malloc(sizeof(real));
        if (p == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"out of memory\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        p->value = x;
        return p;
    }

    double
    getReal(real *v)
    {
        assert(v!=0);
        return v->value;
    }


    void
    displayReal(FILE *fp,void *v)
    {
        assert(v!=0);
        fprintf(fp,"%f",getReal((real *) v));
    }

    void
    freeReal(real *v)
    {
        free(v);
    }
```

and here are my integer.h and real.h files:

integer.h:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #ifndef __INTEGER_INCLUDED__
    #define __INTEGER_INCLUDED__

    typedef struct integer
        {
        int value;
        } integer;

    extern integer *newInteger(int);
    extern int getInteger(integer *);
    extern void displayInteger(FILE *,void *);
    extern void freeInteger(integer *);

    #define PINFINITY IN_MAX
    #define NINFINITY IN_MIN

    #endif
```

real.h:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #ifndef __REAL_INCLUDED__
    #define __REAL_INCLUDED__

    typedef struct real
    {
        double value;
    } real;

    extern real *newReal(double);
    extern double getReal(real *);
    extern void displayReal(FILE *,void *);
    extern void freeReal(real *);

    #define PINFINITY IN_MAX
    #define NINFINITY IN_MIN

    #endif
```

Here is str.h:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #ifndef __STRING_INCLUDED__
    #define __STRING_INCLUDED__

    extern char * getString(char *);
    extern void displayString(FILE *,void *);
    extern void freeString(char *);

    #define PINFINITY IN_MAX
    #define NINFINITY IN_MIN

    #endif
```

and comparator.h:

```
    #ifndef comparator_h
    #define comparator_h

    typedef int (*Comparator)(void*,void*);
    typedef void (*Printer)(FILE*,void*);

    extern int intComparator(void *p, void *q);
    extern int realComparator(void *p, void *q);
    extern int stringComparator(void *p, void *q);

    #endif /* comparator_h */
```

I've been staring at this for so long and have checked everything multiple times and can't figure out why I'm getting these errors.  Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: maybe `comparator.c` need include `integer.h`.

Comment: I have it included already, still getting errors

Comment: _use of undeclared identifier 'integer'_ So It is deleted by overwriting or the such as.

Comment: Check for typos and make sure the include guards (assuming you use them) are unique... if you posted complete code that exhibited the problem it'd be easier to help.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY when you say that it is 'deleted by overwriting or the such as' what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @l.fare Actually I can not believe what the you says. I think that it is probably not possible to read the header file. I can not confirm other things.

Comment: And Vittorio Romeo already pointed out `((integer *) q->value)` typo as `((integer *) q)->value`

Comment: @Dmitri I have added the complete code

Comment: What's in `str.h` and `comparator.h`?

Comment: @Dmitri just added it

Comment: note : macro name of start with `__` is reserved for system.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the parenthesis:

```
return ((integer *) p)->value - ((integer *) q->value);
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

return ((real *) p)->value - ((real *) q)->value;
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- In the first case, you're casting `q->value` to `integer*`.
- In the second case, you're casting `q` to `real*`, then accessing `->value`.

I assume that the first case is an error.

Comment: Unfortunately even with that change, I get the same errors

Comment: @l.fare: cannot reproduce: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ACG2XnSbk5SMvDRd - check your includes.

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple of issues, but first, I want to suggest a code modification to assist in debugging.  You wrote a lot of code in one line.  I suggest that you break the code into parts until you understand it.  Then when it is working, you can combine it together.  Like this:

```
int intComparator(void *p, void *q)
    {
      int rval;
      int p1;
      int q1;

      p1 = (int *)p -> value;
      q1 = (int *)q -> value;
      rval = p1 - q1;
        return (rval);
    }
```

Now, here are two issues that I see:
1. You are attempting to cast p and q as pointers to integers.  I think you need to cast them as pointers to int, not integer.
2. In realcomparator, you are returning an int but you are working with real numbers, I think.  Either you should change the return value to a real, or convert the result to an integer before returning it.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I corrected the error with returning an int when working with doubles (something I overlooked completely). When it comes to the issue of casting those pointers as integers instead of ints, I did so because we are required to make an integer class essentially wrapping our ints.  Integer is a class that was written separately from int and I have included it above.